# Errors when compacting VirtualBox VHD Image

Tags: virtualbox

My host OS is OS X Lion running a Windows XP client with VirtualBox 4.2.0. I'm wanting to make a copy of the image and compact it to share with a colleague. First, I used the VirtualBox command line to clone the image via `clonehd`.

```
VBoxManage clonevdi /path/to/image.vhd /new/path/to/image.vhd
```

Next, I tried compacting the image with the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd /new/path/to/image.vhd --compact
```

In which I'm presented with the following error:

```
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Failed to compact hard disk
VBoxManage: error: Could not compact medium '/new/path/to/image.vhd' (VERR_INVALID_STATE)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Medium, interface IMedium
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleModifyHardDisk(HandlerArg*)" at line 577 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

I've tried my hand at resolving the issue by searching, but I've came up empty handed up to this point. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can only compact VDI images using the VirtualBox commandline *as far as I know*. You can use 3rd party tools to compact a VHD - Google is your friend.

If your host is Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, you should be able to use `compact vdisk` according to the page at *technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252556.aspx*.

In the VirtualBox world, here's how...

```
VBoxManage modifyhd path\to\disk.VDI --compact
```

...if you've created a disk in a different format - e.g. VHD, exec the following command first...

```
VBoxManage clonehd "path\to\vhdformat.vhd" "path\to\vdiformat.vdi" --format vdi
```

[See this example...](http://dantwining.co.uk/2011/07/18/how-to-shrink-a-dynamically-expanding-guest-virtualbox-image/), as well as [this comprehensive example](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/in-search-of-a-light-weight-windows-vagrant-box) by Matt Wrock on how to optimise a VirtualBox VM, ready for packaging.

Comment: I have noticed that when converting from VHD to VDI, the result is already optimized, so you don't have to run --compact on it again.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me just now but I quickly fixed it by just shutting down the virtual machine.

-Looks like you can't shrink virtualbox storage **while it's in use**.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is relevant to this question, since the image that the OP was trying to compact was already a clone/copy of an existing VM.